# If any substring in a string contains the required regex

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, substring

mailto:abcd@gmail.com 
wont match the email regex.
/\A[\w+-.]+@[a-z\d-]+(.[a-z\d-]+)*.[a-z]+\z/i 
I want to check if any substring in the given string matches the regex.
In this case, abcd@gmail.com matches the regex.

Answer (score 0):

In a regular expression, `\A` means "start of string" and `\z` means "end of string". Therefore your pattern is anchored to only match against the **whole** string.

`"mailto:abcd...."` contains a `:` character, which is not allowed by your regex pattern. Therefore the string does not match.

If you remove these anchors, you get the result you're expecting:

```
"mailto:abcd@gmail.com".match(/[\w+-.]+@[a-z\d-]+(.[a-z\d-]+)*.[a-z]+/i)
  #=> #<MatchData "abcd@gmail.com" 1:".c">
```

On another note, your email regex is quite messy! Especially this part:

```
[a-z\d-]+(.[a-z\d-]+)*.[a-z]+
```

What is that supposed to mean? It probably doesn't mean what you think it means... If you could explain the intent here, I'll be able to provide a more accurate pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[A-Za-z0-9_.]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+.[a-z]+` to check if the string contains email address or not.

`[A-Za-z0-9_.]+`  Matches 1 or more characters/ digits/ dot(.)/ underscore(_)

`@` Matches @ in the email address

`[A-Za-z0-9]+` Matches the domain name. For ex: gmail in abcd@gmail.com

`.` Matches the .

`[a-z]+` Matches 1 or more characters. Ex: com in abcd@gmail.com